Google Custom Search API giving error code 400 for no reason when ran by AI
I am trying to run an AI agent with a google search tool on it , but for some weird reason , the google API is behaving pretty weirdly and I dont know the reason.
I have setup a llama_index agent with ReAct AI
and I have created a custom class for google search , which if I try to run from my colab directly , It works smoothly
and when the agent tries to call the same function of the class with exactly same parameters , the google API gives error "400 Bad request Your browser sent an invalid request."
I have tried everything I could , I am 100% its not a problem with the AI and rather problem with the API itself , because just for testing purposes, I also print the URL the AI is hitting to , and it turns out that URL is completely fine and when I try to open same url on my pc , it works properly fine.
This is the code for my class
import urllib.parse
from typing import Optional
import requests
from llama_index.core.schema import Document
from llama_index.core.tools.tool_spec.base import BaseToolSpec
from main_content_extractor import MainContentExtractor

QUERY_URL_TMPL = ("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={key}&cx={engine}&q={query}&num=1")


class GoogleSearchToolSpec(BaseToolSpec):
    """Google Search tool spec."""

    spec_functions = ["google_search"]

    def __init__(self, key: str, engine: str) -> None:
        """Initialize with parameters."""
        self.key = key
        self.engine = engine

    def google_search(self, input: str):
        """
        Make a query to the Google search engine to receive a list of results.

        Args:
            input (str): The query to be passed to Google search.

        Returns :
            Content of top 4 searches on the query in form of MarkDown
        """ 
        url = QUERY_URL_TMPL.format(
            key=self.key, engine=self.engine, query=urllib.parse.quote_plus(input)
        )
        print(url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        json_response = response.json()
        links = []
        for items in json_response['items']:
            links.append(items['link'])

        content_final = "" 
        response = requests.get(links[0])
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'
        content = response.text

        extracted_html = MainContentExtractor.extract(content)
        extracted_markdown = MainContentExtractor.extract(content, output_format="markdown")
        content_final += extracted_markdown

        return content_final

And just to confirm that the code is all good, I even ran the code separate from AI and it works properly
here is an image of the output ->

but when the same tool is used by AI I get this error ->

idk why I am getting this error
It was working fine just last time I ran it, idk what happened
When I hit the same API route with same parameters with my pc or with the same colab environment , it works
but when AI tries to fetch it , it fails
